# Why this process won't be killed?

Tags: windows, process

(1) The process that I'd like to kill is ZhuDongFangYu.exe, which is part of the antivirus suit that I currently use. This process is still running even the main antivirus program is turned off, but everytime I try to kill it,I get a "the operation is denied" msg,so do you have any idea?

(2) And I checked the process in the Process Explorer,here's the snap-shot:
[image]

It seems that the ZhuDongFangYu(which mean active protecting in Chinese) exe resides in services.exe, so that's why the process can not be killed?

And why I don't see services.exe in task-management window?

THANKS!!

Comment: Hi, why do u want to kill that process? Is it harm for your sys? 
Accoding to your screenshot, there is "ksafesvc.exe",did you install more than two sys-tools that have similiar function,You think is that OK for your OS and ur regular use?
Have you tried the method from Venu Yanamandra? Please tell the result.Many thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The process that I'd like to kill is ZhuDongFangYu.exe, which is part of the antivirus suit that I currently use. This process is still running even the main antivirus program is turned off, but everytime I try to kill it,I get a "the operation is denied" msg,so do you have any idea?

1. The "main antivirus program" is not really "main"; it's probably just the control interface.
2. In Windows, processes have ACLs. For example, a user is only allowed to kill their own processes.

   Double-click `ZhuDongFangYu.exe`, choose *Security* and click *Permissions*.
3. Some anti-virus software install kernel hooks that prevent you from killing them irrespective of ACLs. (An example is Avast.)

   In such cases, you must use the "correct" method of stopping the antivirus -- usually by using its official graphical interface.

Answer (score 2):

Services.exe would spawn new processes. Once its task is complete it would not be seen. and the console that you see as part of services is MMC (microsoft management console.)

I suggest you stop the service, remove from startup, and also follow the below process:

open:
run prompt -> type msconfig -> select startup -> and uncheck the service that you identify.

for the above method to be successful without any manual process kill, please restart your system.